# Efeito de transição no menu com angular

Tags: javascript, html, css, angularjs, css-transições

Eu qria por um efeito de transição no menu ao dar um ng show ou ng hide (clicar no botão de abrir).

```
 <a class="sandwich panel" ng-class="{'open' : isOpen}" ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen; toggleCustom()">
        <div>
        </div>
    </a>
</nav>
    <div ng-hide="custom">
        <ul class="menu-mob">
             <li class="menu-option color-menu-selected" ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen; toggleCustom()"><a ui-sref="home">Home</a></li>
            <li class="menu-option color-menu" ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen; toggleCustom()"><a ui-sref="vandergama">Client</a></li>
            <li class="menu-option color-menu" ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen; toggleCustom()"><a ui-sref="portifolio">Portifólio</a></li>
            <li class="menu-option color-menu" ng-click="isOpen=!isOpen; toggleCustom()"><a ui-sref="contato">Contato</a></li>
        </ul>
    </div>
```

Angular:

```
app.controller("app", function($scope){
$scope.custom = true;
$scope.toggleCustom = function() {
        $scope.custom = $scope.custom === false ? true: false;
    };
});
```

Meu Css não iria ajudar muito, ms a ideia é que ao abrir o menu, tenha um efeito assim -> [AQUI](https://plnkr.co/edit/?p=preview) <-

Comment: seu plunker linkado esta vazio e acho que seu css ajuda sim ein.. rs

Comment: Exatamente como o @andrepaulo disse, seu CSS vai ajudar sim e é até melhor criar no CSS.

Comment: Vixe, foi mal. Segue esse link então https://docs.angularjs.org/api/ng/directive/ngShow, é o 1º exemplo. Cara, falei do css pq só to usando pra um efeitozinho no botão e pra preencher a aba do menu. Ms n to usando pro efeito.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

instale a biblioteca angular-animate.min

ultize a classe ng-leave-active no css

exemplo:

```
 .menu-option {
    -moz-transition:transform 0.8s;
    -webkit-transition:transform 0.8s;
    -ms-transition:transform 0.8s;
    -o-transition:transform 0.8s;
    transition:transform 0.8s;
}

.menu-option.ng-leave-active {
  -moz-transform: scale(0.1);
  -webkit-transform: scale(0.1);
  -ms-transform: scale(0.1);
  -o-transform: scale(0.1);
  transform: scale(0.1);
}
```